# CSS Positioning and Floating

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, floating

[my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQ9vN/1/)

I want to write

```
`playing Stephan Malkmus - Out of Reaches radio`
```

but it become line by line in the fiddle.

How can i wtite it in a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html code is semantically incorrect, a div element is a tag that have a block display, so it occupies the space of a row.

For inline element use the `span` tag which is an inline tag and solve your problem without using css but only the correct use of HTML5 features.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mQ9vN/3/)

Answer (score 4):

add

```
display: inline;
```

to `#channelInfo` (since div elements are, by default, block elements)

example: http://jsfiddle.net/c3QYp/

Answer (score 1):

```
display:inline-block;
```

In case you need to add a padding or a margin to the text.